# Python Docker: Get Containers memory usage, CPU percentage programmatically in python docker

Tags: python, docker

As command "docker stats" gives details like:(I have put just header, not values)

```
CONTAINER ID        NAME                      CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
```

I want the above details using python script. I have done following:

`client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock')
  for i in client.containers.list():
     print(i.stats)`

But not getting any useful information using i.stats and it's attribute.
What should I do to get above details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`stats` is a function. So you need to call it as `i.stats()`. It also streams the result by default as a python generator. If you want to get the current stats only, you can use the `stream=False` parameter.

```
client = docker.DockerClient(base_url='unix:///var/run/docker.sock')
for i in client.containers.list():
     print(i.stats(stream=False))
```

If you want to keep printing the stats realtime:

```
for stat in i.stats():
    print(stat)
```